# catch server redirects in angular router

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am using angularjs routing. When I navigate to a view angular makes the request for the HTML defined in the templateUrl of the route. However, in a certain scenario - where the user's session has expired - the server returns a redirect. This redirect is followed and the resulting HTML is placed in the ng-view div.

This results in the login page being embedded within the original page which is no good. How can I make angular redirect the whole browser window to the redirect URL rather than just the contents of the ng-view?